# Script Tag Binding Method

Tags: javascript, dom-events

The following code is NOT working as expected. I am using "Script Tag Binding Method" to have the events fired. Can you please FIX this?

```
<html>    
    <head>    
                <title>
                    Example
                </title>    
    </head>    
    <body>    
        <input type="button" name="cmdScriptTag" value="Script Tag">    
                <script language="javascript" For="cmdScriptTag" Event="OnClick">    
                    alert("Script Tag Binding Method.");    
                </script>    
        </body>    
</html>
```

Comment: sorry but what is a "Script Tag Binding Method"? 
and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: This is not plain HTML (where it would be invalid). What serverside processing language do you use? Please tag your question appropriately.

Comment: When you click on the button the alert should show-up. And this is one of the methods in hooking up events to controls.

Comment: @Bergi - This is an MS-proprietary thing. The `event` attribute "Sets or retrieves the event for which the script is written" as [mentioned at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ie/ms533746%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with an example that uses `for` too. @user1054625 - You should use another method to hook up your event handlers. Is there any reason why you're doing it this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you have:

```
> <script language="javascript" For="cmdScriptTag" Event="OnClick">
```

The *language* attribute for script elements was deprecated in HTML 4 and is removed in HTML5. The *type* attribute is required in HTML 4 and optional in HTML5. In practice, it's not necessary, you can just use:

```
<script>
  /* content */
</script>
```

The [*for*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ie/ms533870%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) attribute for script elements is a Microsoft proprietary feature that is not part of any standard and probably not supported at all outside of IE (and possibly not supported by current IE versions). It was reserved for future use in the [DOM 2 HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-66979266) but never implemented for script elements (as far as I know). It applied only to [label elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-for) in HTML 4.01, same in [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-label-element.html#attr-label-for).

<strike>As far as I'm aware, there never was an *event* attribute, it may have been related to the *for* attribute but neither are listed at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772960%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).</strike>

The [*event*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ie/ms533746%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) attribute is similar to the *for* attribute: it's an IE feature that's not widely implemented and associates the script within a script element with an event for another element. Essentially it's the same as using other standards compliant methods to associate script with elements and events but a lot clunkier.

In any case, to associate a function with an element that will be called when the element receives a certain event, you can use a variety of methods. The most robust and widely implemented are inline listeners, e.g.:

```
<input type="button" name="cmdScriptTag" value="Script Tag"
 onclick="alert('Script Tag Binding Method.');">
```

Though generally the script body is put in a function that is called by the listener, e.g.

```
<script>
  function foo(){
      alert('Script Tag Binding Method.');
  }
</script>
<input type="button" name="cmdScriptTag" value="Call foo"
 onclick="foo();">
```

You can also attach listeners dynamically using various methods such as [addEventListener](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Events-20001113/events.html#Events-EventTarget-addEventListener), which is explained on the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener) (MDN).

Comment: The `event` attribute "Sets or retrieves the event for which the script is written" as [mentioned at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ie/ms533746%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), with an example that uses `for` too. Also mentioned on [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535892%28VS.85%29.aspx). You are right to recommend other methods.

Comment: Ha, I hit that page and misinterpreted the first part so didn't get to the good part. Thanks for tidying up. :-)

Comment: Here is the URL i have got from your links. This is what i am trying to do: (Thanks for pointing me right direction) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533746(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @user1054625 - _Why_ are you trying to do it that way? Even if you get it working it will only work in IE, and the inline `onclick` attribute method that Rob showed is simpler...

Comment: @ nnnnnn, We do have code in Classical ASP project like this. So i am learning how many ways we can have event handling in ASP using JavaScript.